# What do you call the super class and subclass when initializing?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

```
Super class = new Sub();
```

Is `Super` called the reference and is `Sub` the actual class?

I've read about one being compile time and the other being run time, but I don't know how that affects me as a programmer or which one is which?

Comment: I created the other question early but was unable to delete it. There were too many answers to change the original question. I already asked for them to delete that question.
Also, it's not a duplicate because the other one used an interface as the super class. This one uses just a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here `Super` is the type of object reference whereas `Sub` is the type of the actual object which is created in the heap.

Comment: Ok. That seems to make sense when using Eclipse. The 'Sub' is colored the same as its constructor.